# Getting chart data to work within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all i am in need of some help trying to figure out how to pass a string into an array field for a chart. The chart i am using is this [http://www.highcharts.com/]

Here is the chart code:

```
 function drawChart(theDATA)
    {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {renderTo: 'container',defaultSeriesType: 'column'},
            title: {text: 'March 2010 Confirmed User Visit\'s'},
            xAxis: {categories: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']},
            yAxis: {min: 0,title: {text: 'User Visit\'s'}},
            legend: {layout: 'vertical',backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',style: {left: '100px',top: '70px',bottom: 'auto'}},
            tooltip: {formatter: function() {return this.y;}},
            plotOptions: {column: {pointPadding: 0.2,borderWidth: 0}},
                series: [{name: 'Confirmed Users Visit\'s',
                data: [theDATA]
            }]
        }); 
    }
```

With the code above, you would think that theDATA would work but it does not display the data within it.

Say that theDATA is '2,5,4,7,8,9'. If i had this:

```
 data: [2,5,4,7,8,9]
```

Then it would work just fine. But if i use those same numbers...

```
theData = "2,5,4,7,8,9"
data: [theData]
```

It does nothing on the chart...

So what am i doing wrong????

David

**EDIT**

Added

```
 var theDATA = theDATA.split(",");
 for ( var t = 0; t < theDATA.length; ++t ) theDATA[t] = parseInt(theDATA[t]);
```

so...

```
function drawChart(theDATA)
{
 var theDATA = theDATA.split(",");
 for ( var t = 0; t < theDATA.length; ++t ) theDATA[t] = parseInt(theDATA[t]);

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {renderTo: 'container',defaultSeriesType: 'column'},
        title: {text: 'March 2010 Confirmed User Visit\'s'},
        xAxis: {categories: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']},
        yAxis: {min: 0,title: {text: 'User Visit\'s'}},
        legend: {layout: 'vertical',backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',style: {left: '100px',top: '70px',bottom: 'auto'}},
        tooltip: {formatter: function() {return this.y;}},
        plotOptions: {column: {pointPadding: 0.2,borderWidth: 0}},
            series: [{name: 'Confirmed Users Visit\'s',
            data: [theDATA]
        }]
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data expects array.

try:

```
data: theDATA.split(',');
```

if you are passing the string.

You can also convert theDATA to array before passing it to the drawChart function

### EDIT

i found the problem

```
data: [3,4,6]
```

works, but:

```
data["3","4","6"]
```

doesn't work, and that is what you get after split, an array of strings, but it expects an array of integers

one solution is

```
data: theDATA.split(",").map(function(element){ return parseInt(element)})
```

the other solution is that you from your chartData.asp return JSON array.
So instead of returning "2,3,4,5,6" you return [3,4,5,6,7] and call you function with

```
drawChart(eval(xmlhttp.responseText));
```

combined with

```
data: thisData
```

Comment: Did not seem to work... here is the result of that http://nextbowluser.com/text/column-basic.asp

Comment: well no wonder it doesn't work
take a look at your response at http://nextbowluser.com/text/chartData.asp?q=&sid=0.15418553551807856  (use view page source)

this shuld be ONLY coma separated string (i.e. 2,4,5,62,7,2,4), not whole div, and bunch of javascript

i sugest you start fresh or find some tutorial on that chart engine

Comment: You know what, i forgot about having all that data in my asp chartdata.asp page. I took it out and now it only passes back "7,7,0,0,0,0,0,8,16,1,6,5,1,1,8,15,22,1,5,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,8,0,8,7,6". But running the code again, it doesnt plot it on the chart???

Comment: The drawChart(eval(xmlhttp.responseText)); worked but the json type did not it seems. It only loaded up one column when i did it that way. Thanks! :o)

Comment: Well... i just tested the code out in IE and it seems IE has a problem with the "data: theDATA.split(",").map(function(element){ return parseInt(element)})}".. any solution for IE?

The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: if you are usung eval, there is no need for split, just use data: thisData